# Undefined reference with glfw3 using g++ on windows

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, glfw, undefined-reference

I'm trying to create an opengl project for [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Creating-a-window), and I can't get my program to compile.

The current problem here is that every glfw functions are undefined, but they exist in glfw3.h.

The glfw3 files are from [the glfw download page](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) (x64 version).

Here is a copy of the logs:

```
make
=== SRC ===
src/glad.c src/main.cpp
=== OBJ ===
bin/glad.o bin/main.o
===== Creating file bin/glad.o ===
C:/cygnus/cygwin-b20/H-i586-cygwin32/bin/mkdir -p bin/
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -I./include -o bin/glad.o -c src/glad.c
===== Creating file bin/main.o ===
C:/cygnus/cygwin-b20/H-i586-cygwin32/bin/mkdir -p bin/
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -I./include -o bin/main.o -c src/main.cpp
C:/MinGW/bin/g++  -L./libs -o build/program.exe bin/glad.o bin/main.o -lglfw3
bin/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [program.exe] Erreur 1
```

I'm using the following main.cpp file:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    glfwInit();

    return 0;
}
```

And the following makefile:

```
CXX = C:/MinGW/bin/g++
FAKEPATH = C:/cygnus/cygwin-b20/H-i586-cygwin32/bin/

CXXFLAGS  = -W -Wall -ansi -Wno-deprecated
LDLIBS = -lglfw3

TARGET  = program.exe

LIB_DIR = -L./libs
INC_DIR = -I./include

SRC = $(shell $(FAKEPATH)find src/ -type f \( -iname \*.cpp -o -iname \*.c \))
OBJ = $(patsubst src/%,bin/%,$(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRC))))


all: directories $(TARGET)

test:
    echo $(FAKEPATHEXISTS)

directories:
    @$(FAKEPATH)echo === SRC ===
    @$(FAKEPATH)echo $(SRC)
    @$(FAKEPATH)echo === OBJ ===
    @$(FAKEPATH)echo $(OBJ)
    @$(FAKEPATH)mkdir -p bin
    @$(FAKEPATH)mkdir -p build

compileAndRun: all
    build/$(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIB_DIR) -o build/$@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

bin/%.o: src/%.c
    @$(FAKEPATH)echo ===== Creating file $@ ===
    $(FAKEPATH)mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(INC_DIR) -o $@ -c $<

bin/%.o: src/%.cpp
    @$(FAKEPATH)echo ===== Creating file $@ ===
    $(FAKEPATH)mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(INC_DIR) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    @$(FAKEPATH)rm -rf bin/

cleaner: clean
    @$(FAKEPATH)rm -rf build/
```

And finally, my files are sorted like this:

[image: files]

I'm using MinGW for g++ and cygwin for the linux commands.

Any help or try would be really appreciated ! (I really don't know where the problem came from)
Thanks !

Note: I already searched on google a lot without finding any working solution (including several stack overflow questions)

Comment: Is the libs lookup path correct? Does it need to be   ../libs instead of  ./libs?

Comment: I get a "cannot find -lglfw3" when I set LIB_DIR to -L../libs

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this.

The first things I had to do is add `#define GLFW_DLL` in my main.cpp.

After doing this I had the error `Undefined reference to '_imp__glfwInit'`. To solve this error I had to remove the *.a files in my /libs, and then I moved my .dll file to the root of the project (To avoid a missing dll error).